# Windows machines can't access microsoft.com or AV-sites from my network

Tags: windows, dns

Please excuse me if this question is off-topic.

None of the Windows machines(1*Vista, 1*Win7, 1*Win8) on my network can access microsoft.com or AV-sites unless I set 8.8.8.8 as DNS-server. The strange thing with this is that Androids, iOS and Linux devices can access these sites. I tried taking the Win7 laptop to another network (same ISP), and there it managed to access microsoft.com.

I cannot find anything useful on my Thomson TG784 Gateway.

This is a mystery.

Comment: The most probable answer is that you've been infected with a malware. I've seen the _exact_ behavior with a malware called Conficker (or DownUp).

Comment: **nslookup microsoft.com** on the win7 laptop gives the IP addresses 64.4.11.37 and 65.55.58.201.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this website to check if you have been infected by Conficker : http://www.confickertest.com/

> Explanation:
>
> Conficker (aka Downadup, Kido) is known to block access to over 100
>   anti-virus and security websites.
>
> If you are blocked from loading the remote images in the first row of
>   the top table above (AV/security sites) but not blocked from loading
>   the images in the second row (websites of alternative operating
>   systems) then your Windows PC may be infected by Conficker (or some
>   other malicious software).
>
> If you can see all six images in both rows of the top table, you are
>   either not infected by Conficker, or you may be using a proxy server,
>   in which case you will not be able to use this test to make an
>   accurate determination, since Conficker will be unable to block you
>   from viewing the AV/security sites.

Comment: Thanks, @Techbrunch. the confickertest.com page displays the same result for both my Linux computer and my newly restored Win7 laptop. I can still not access microsoft.com after restoring the Win7 laptop using the boot alternative that reinstalls windows. Either the recovery partition also is infected, or the problem is elsewhere...

Comment: You should check you DNS settings on your modem. Your modem could have been hacked and unless you set manually you DNS settings your computer will use the one set on you modem. What is the model of you modem ?

Comment: It is a Thomson TG784. I have checked the two DNS settings. The first one belongs to the ISP and the second one is 8.8.8.8